# How to assign web.config values to html elements with logic applied to the values

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net, web-config

Here is my situation:
I have a setting in app config that is supposed to control whether some  controls are enabled or not.

Here is how im doing it:

```
<dx:ASPxButton runat="server"  Enabled="<%$ AppSettings: EnableGeoPropertiesEdit %>" />
```

and it works. My problem is that i have to apply the same property to this HTML input

```
<input type="button" runat="server" id="getElevationButton" disabled=?????/>
```

I have to disable this control and cant find a simple way to do it

The best i could come up with is

```
<input type="button" runat="server" id="getElevationButton" disabled= "<%= (!bool.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["EnableGeoPropertiesEdit"])) %>"/>
```

but to my surprise that doesnt even compile.
I thought about using jquery to get that property from the other controls but i stumble on the part where i would have to negate it.

Any suggestions?

Comment: why not use codebehind to do it ?

Comment: Something like on_page_load find control and change its state?

Is there any performance penalty to doing this on code behind as opposed to do it via markup? 

(i always think things on markup happen at the best possible moment, i.e, i dont have to worry about hooking to the correct event

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following HeartBleed's suggestion, i ended up doing

```
protected override void OnLoadComplete(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
      base.OnLoadComplete(sender, e);
      getElevationButton.Attributes["disabled"] = (!bool.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["EnableGeoPropertiesEdit"])).ToString();
}
```